# Start GTK apk based on Python

Tags: python, gtk

How to start application based on Python + Glade?

```
startx python apk.py
```

is not working. I can run application like Firefox from text mode:

```
startx firefox
```

Comment: startx starts X server, you run apps `python apk.py`

Answer (score 0):

The client argument has some parsing rules that you can find in the man pages for `startx` and `xinit`.

Basically, you need to have the client start with a slash or dot. This works:

```
$ startx /usr/bin/python apk.py
```

Or the common cheat to use path from env:

```
$ startx /usr/bin/env python apk.py
```

If the program can start by itself (correct #! line at start in case of python), you can just

```
$ startx ./apk.py
```